# Transact SQL - View Data Type Schronization Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I working on an auto synchronization project where I want to get the data types from a View on SQL Server 2008 R2 and compare it to a table in the same database. I am familiar with syscolumns, However, this only appears to work with tables, not Views. Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

Essentially, if View_A has a new column added to it, I need to add the column to Table_A with the same properties as View_A so that all data types, lengths, and fields on Table_A are always the same as View_A.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using syscolumns and its relatives anymore. These backward compatibility views are provided only to prevent existing code from breaking; you should be using the catalog views instead (sys.tables, sys.columns, sys.objects, etc). They contain much richer information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.columns` includes column information for views:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Test_View
AS
SELECT * FROM sys.objects

SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test_View')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about syscolumns only showing columns of base tables, but you can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourView'
```

Comment: +1: I really need to get in the habit of using INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead of the SQL "sys" tables.

Comment: @Tom why? INFORMATION_SCHEMA views are not being developed any further, so you miss out on key information that you have to capture from the sys catalog views (not tables) anyway. For example, try to figure out if an index is filtered or if one of its columns is included using INFORMATION_SCHEMA or even sp_helpindex.

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA is the ANSI standard. Of course, most of my clients aren't too concerned with having to suddenly change their RDBMS, so I suppose that you're right. In reality I use the sys views (sorry for the slip-up earlier) in almost all cases.

Comment: Lots of things are ANSI standard, but the non-standard choices are often better. When functionality is equivalent, I'll choose the standard; otherwise I'll choose the one that works better. Let's face it, do you think changing to INFORMATION_SCHEMA is going to be your biggest bottleneck if you switch to a different RDBMS, even to one that follows the standard the exact same way?

Answer (score 0):

The columns in `sys.columns` are for both views and tables.

So, you should be able to do the same as a table, i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyViewName')
```